# This site can’t be reached WordPress Google Cloud Platform

Tags: wordpress, ssl-certificate, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-launcher

I am using Google Cloud Platform.

I successfully setup a GCE Google Click to Deploy WordPress, pointed the A Record of our domain to the IP Address: 35.233.209.192 and then the domain, connectech.us, and it worked fine.

I am able to login to the Admin Dashboard.

I tried to install a LetsEncrypt SSL certificate and now I get an error:

> 'This site can't be reached'

I can't access my MySQL database, nor the website nor the WordPress admin dashboard.

I have added the IP address 35.233.209.192 connectech.us to my Mac Host File and entered 8.8.8.8 in my network router.

I get the same issue in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I can see the website connectech.us, is the issue solved now?

Comment: Gave up on finding how to resolve this issue and moved my Wordpress site to DreamHost. The lack of support using GCP is the main reason and DreamHost at least gives some support. My issue apparently has something do with DNS and my Mac computer not being able to view the site. I may try another project later and see if I can resolve it.